# How to do manual change in moodle database?

Tags: database, moodle

I want to do some changes in the moodle database. I want to login to our moodle database, In `mdl_config` table there is a row whose `name` column contains `supportemail`. The `value` column specifies the email address which is used as From address in outgoing system emails, I want to configure it to be the same email address as our SMTP username. Apparently, the Moodle UI does not give access to this, so this needs to be changed manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change 'supportemail' from the UI. Site admin > Server > Support contact (in Moodle 3.5, I've not checked other versions).

If you are in doubt, there is a search box in the site admin area (either the block or the main page, depending on Moodle version) - searching for 'supportemail' finds what you are looking for.

If, however, you want to change settings manually, simply open up the database in a suitable database interface (e.g. [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/), [PHPMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)), edit the value, then purge your site caches (Site admin > Development > Purge all caches)

Comment: I did everything as you said before, still it's not working. I even tried manually too. And i tried purging all the caches too. Not working.

Comment: Sorry, I can't offer any further advice. I've made changes like that hundreds of times without any problems (across a wide variety of sites).